# Is there a non-linear combination of basis vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra

How would a non-linear combination of basis be given as? Would the non-linear combination of $2$ independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ also give vectors outside the span of the two vectors?

Comment: I'm kind of confused by what you mean by a non-linear combination of basis vectors? Any operation outside of addition and scalar multiplication may or may not be linear, and they may or may not be outside the normal span of the vectors

Comment: @wjmccann Yes, exactly, that's exactly my question. While any operation outside of vector addition and scalar multiplication could be nonlinear but I havent any operation other than them during the combination of vectors. Since it is specified "linear" combination. I want to know if there is a non-linear combination or if saying combination of basis is same as saying a linear combination of vectors

Comment: Ah ok yeah I have an example I'll put it in an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are thinking of geometric vectors like $(1, 2, 3)$ then an example of a non-linear combination of $(x_1, y_1, z_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2, z_2)$ is $(y_1 z_2, z_1 x_2, x_1 y_2).$ Using this, the combination of $(1, 1, 0)$ and $(1, 1, 0)$ (i.e. the same vector) is $(0, 0, 1)$ which is clearly outside of the span of $(1, 1, 0)$ and $(1, 1, 0)$.

Comment: Isn't $(y_1+z_2,z_1+x_2,x_1+y_2))$ linear combination but out of the span of the said vectors?

Comment: No, it's not a linear combination because of the permutations of the elements. To be a linear combination it needs to have the form $(a x_1 + b x_2, a y_1 + b y_2, a z_1 + b z_2).$

Answer (score 1):

In a linear space that also allows multiplication of its objects, e.g. a space of functions, you can certainly have non-linear combinations like $f(x)^3 g(x)$.

Comment: Yes, that's why I wanted to know particularly about vectors since raising a vector to its power is the dot product of the vector.

Comment: @GRANZER. Mathematical objects can not be vectors in isolation. Only sets can have the properties that make them vector/linear spaces. In general, only linear combinations are allowed from objects in linear spaces. Many linear spaces however have additional structure that make other combinations allowed.

Comment: @GRANZER. Also note that the notation $\vec{v}^2$ is not really "$\vec{v}$ raised to the power of $2$" but rather a shorthand notation for $\vec{v} \cdot \vec{v}$ and probably based on the fact that $\vec{v} \cdot \vec{v} = v^2,$ where $v = |\vec{v}|.$

Answer (score 0):

The linear combination is the most general notion of combination that I know of. Given a subset $C$ of a vector space over a field $\mathbb{F}$,

- Linear combination: $\alpha_1 v_1 + \alpha_2 v_2 + \ldots + \alpha_n v_n$, where $v_1, \ldots, v_n \in C$ and $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n \in \mathbb{F}$.
- Affine combination: $\alpha_1 v_1 + \alpha_2 v_2 + \ldots + \alpha_n v_n$, where $v_1, \ldots, v_n \in C$ and $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n \in \mathbb{F}$ such that $\alpha_1 + \ldots + \alpha_n = 1$.
- Convex combination: $\alpha_1 v_1 + \alpha_2 v_2 + \ldots + \alpha_n v_n$, where $v_1, \ldots, v_n \in C$ and $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n \in [0, \infty) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that $\alpha_1 + \ldots + \alpha_n = 1$ (this only makes sense when $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$).

Note that all of them are linear combinations. The set of all linear combinations is the *span* of $C$. This is the smallest vector subspace containing $C$.

The set of all affine combinations is the *affine hull*.  This is the smallest affine subspace (meaning a vector subspace that has been translated by a fixed vector) containing $C$.

The set of all convex combinations forms the *convex hull*. This is the smallest convex subset containing $C$.

(When given a Schauder basis, you can also consider infinite linear combinations, e.g. Fourier series. But, usually I hear them referred to as linear combinations as well.)

Comment: There's also conic combinations, which require $\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n$ to be positive, but not that they sum to $1$.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there are lots of vector operations that can be non-linear, here is what it requires for an operation to be linear

For a transformation $T: \mathbb{R}^n \mapsto \mathbb{R}^m $, $T(\vec x)$ is linear if and only if

1. $T(\vec x + \vec y) = T(\vec x) + T(\vec y)$ $\forall \vec x, \vec y \in \mathbb{R}^n$

   2. $T(c\vec x) = cT(\vec x)$ $\forall \vec x \in\mathbb{R}^n, \forall c \in \mathbb{R}$

One particular transformation that does not fit this description is $T: \mathbb{R}^2 \mapsto \mathbb{R}^2 | T(\vec x) = \vec x + \vec 1$

Notice this is because

$$
T(c\vec x) = c\vec x + 1 \neq c(\vec x + 1)
$$

That is just an example of a non-linear vector operation, try to come up with another!

Comment: My doubt is about the linear/non-linear combination of vectors, and not on linear functions or transformations.